# How to get my ReSharper quick fix for generating documentation headers back?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, stylecop

I have been using Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2.  One feature I use frequently is hitting Alt-Enter to get to the quickfixes for StyleCop violations and/or ReSharper code inspection violations.

I recently installed another VS extension, unrelated to ReSharper.  After doing so, Alt-Enter no longer opens the quickfix menu if the violation is for a missing documentation header.  It does open the quickfix menu for (at least some) other violations, but not for missing documentation headers.

I have uninstalled the other VS extension, but that did not help.  I have been unable to figure out how to make it start working again.  How can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Eventually I went to the ReSharper menu, then "Extension Manager".  It showed that I had no ReSharper extensions installed.  I searched the available extensions for "StyleCop", and found several.  I more or less randomly decided that "StyleCop by JetBrains" sounded good, and installed it.  Now it's working again.